# JavaScript fireEvent not a function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to make the game Battleship in JavaScript for a school assignment, and I'm stuck trying to create the opponent AI. I've created an event for when I click a cell in the grids:

```
function addListener(evt) {
    evt.addEventListener('click', function(){
        //bunch of code
    });
}
```

Now I run this function `addListener` every time I create a new cell in the grid in my nested for loop:

```
yourCell.setAttribute('id', evt + String(a) + String(b));
addListener(yourCell);
```

What I want now is for the opponent to run this click event when I've made my turn, so I wrote this just to test out the `fireEvent` function:

```
function enemyTurn() {
    document.getElementById('yourGrid00').fireEvent('onclick');
}
```

According to the second code example, I set the ID of the cell to `'yourGrid00'`, which I've confirmed by inspecting the html code after the JavaScript code has been run, and the function `enemyTurn()` will never run before each cell has been created and assigned an ID.

What I do not understand is that I get the following error on the `fireEvent` line:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

`fireEvent` is a really old method which is only supported on Internet Explorer versions 8 and lower. You should instead use [**`dispatchEvent`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent) if you want to handle up-to-date browsers.

> *Dispatches an `Event` at the specified `EventTarget`, invoking the affected `EventListeners` in the appropriate order. The normal event processing rules (including the capturing and optional bubbling phase) apply to events dispatched manually with `dispatchEvent()`.*

You have to create the `Event` manually though - you can't just call `dispatchEvent('onclick')`. I've pulled the first bit of the following code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5352709/1317805).

```
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    false, false, false, false, 0, null);

function enemyTurn() {
    document.getElementById('yourGrid00').dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/p1axbc47/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems to work :) I was just googling how to simulate a click and I stumbled upon fireEvent and found documentation on I thought it was still in use.

Comment: Care to explain what the deal with all the attributes of the initMouseEvent is about?

Comment: @TorsteinRøsok these set up what the mouse event is, where the event happened and a few other details. MDN has documentation on it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.initMouseEvent. `event.initMouseEvent(type, canBubble, cancelable, view,  detail, screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY,  ctrlKey, altKey, shiftKey, metaKey,  button, relatedTarget);`